# How to avoid wrapping of elements in a long list with scrollbars in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have a long flex list which should wrap it's items (Buttons) when they have not enough space (flex-wrap). However, as soon as the list gets a scrollbar, the items will be wrapped in Firefox even if there is enough space.

Chrome displays the buttons side by side as expected.

(I use Vue here, to keep the HTML simple. It actually just creates the text/button element 30 times)

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
})
```

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  position: absolute; 
  height: 100vh; 
  overflow: auto;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div class="container" id="app">
  <div v-for="(i, index) in 30" :index="i">
    Text
    <div class="row">
      <button>Button 1</button>
      <button>Button 2</button>
    </div>
    <hr />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: when I go full page with your snippet, I see the flex container taking the whole available space in the viewport as expected by `height: 100vh;`. I'm using firefox. Then your next problem is not about the vertical space but how to correctly display elements inline. You should have your buttons with `display: inline-block;` to start with

Comment: Then you should try to extend the width of `.container` with something like a fixed width... I tried `fit-content` and didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see the flex container taking the whole available space in the viewport as expected by `height: 100vh;`. I'm using firefox.

Then your next problem is not about the vertical space but how to correctly display elements inline. You should have your buttons with `display: inline-block;` to start with.

Then you should try to set the width of the closest parent... I added at first a rule to the parent elements `.container > div` so that their width is set to `width:fit-content;`. Later I moved it to the `.container`, and better sized the scrollbar feature using `overflow-y: scroll`.

When using `overflow: auto` it will show the scrollbar only when needed but the container size will not take into account the possibility that the scrollbar will be shown or not. So in case they will be shown, they will occupy inner space covering content.

When using `overflow: scroll` it will always show the scrollbar and the container size will always take them into account.

To make the container size adaptive also when using `overflow: auto` there are several options like this one used here:

`scrollbar-gutter: stable;`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scrollbar-gutter

But in the end, to have a better control over the width of your container, you can check via javascript if the content is overflowing the container, and only in that case add (or unset in the opposite case) the css attribute `overflow: scroll`.

I also added the `box-sizing: border-box` to avoid containers to occupy some extra vertical space.

Here's the demo showing two "apps" next to each other, one with a container having content not overflowing (thus no scrollbar) and another one having content overflowing (thus showing scrollbar):

This solution refreshes the containers in case the window was resized and adds/remove the scrollbars if the overflow condition of contents changed.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app1", 
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app2", 
})

refreshPage();
window.addEventListener('resize', refreshPage);

function refreshPage(){
  const app1 = document.getElementById('app1');
  const app2 = document.getElementById('app2');

  const isApp1Overflowing = app1.scrollHeight > app1.clientHeight;
  const isApp2Overflowing = app2.scrollHeight > app2.clientHeight;
  
  if (isApp1Overflowing)
    app1.style.overflowY = 'scroll';
  else
    app1.style.overflowY = 'unset';

  if (isApp2Overflowing)
    app2.style.overflowY = 'scroll';
  else
    app2.style.overflowY = 'unset';
}
```

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  /*added borders to container to better highlights its size*/
  border: solid 1px black;  
  /*it will take 100% of viewport height*/
  height: 100vh;   
  /*scroll instead of auto to have the scrollbar not occupying inner space*/
  /*overflow-y: auto;*/
  /*scrollbar-gutter: stable;*/
  /*fit-content will adapt to content, otherwise if unset will go 100%*/
  width: fit-content;
  /*to add some padding from the container borders*/
  padding: 5px;  
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align:top;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row button{
  /*to have the buttons next to each other*/
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div class="container" id="app1" style="display: inline-block">
  <div v-for="(i, index) in 5" :index="i">
    Text
    <div class="row">
      <button>Button 1</button>
      <button>Button 2</button>
    </div>
    <hr />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container" id="app2" style="display: inline-block">
  <div v-for="(i, index) in 25" :index="i">
    Text
    <div class="row">
      <button>Button 1</button>
      <button>Button 2</button>
    </div>
    <hr />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Using overflow-y:scroll works, however I want to use "auto" to not show scrollbars when not necessary. When setting it back to auto, the buttons break again in Firefox. In my app the whole list is a popup dialog positioned absolute and yes, the height: 100vh is intentional.

Comment: I updated my answer explaining the issue with container size when using `overflow:scroll/auto` and added a new css attribute to accomodate that

Comment: I didn't knew scrollbar-gutter: stable; This works as well, but reserves the space for the scrollbar even if not needed, which looks ugly in my real life app. Isn't there a simple way to just keep the items aside as Chrome and other browsers do? To me this looks like a bug in Firefox finally.

Comment: I'm afraid that the only safe way to make the container size be consistent with its content (depending on the presence of the scrollbar) is to control it via js. Like checking if the content overflows its container and in that case add the css property `overflow: scroll;`. I couldn't get there with css only unfortunately

Comment: I updated the answer using the js approach. When you'll run the snippet, both the "apps" will have their contents overflow their container so they will have both the vertical scrollbar that won't refresh when resizing the window.

Comment: The latest update shows the javascript approach in action that adds or remove the css attribute `overflow: scroll` depending on the contents overflowing or not its container. The demo shows two containers next to each other, the first one having few items and the second one having a lot of them and overflowing. Plus it refreshes the scrollbar presence on window resize.

Comment: Thanks Diego! I hoped for a CSS only solution, but it works.